# dplyr:: How to use SE and `%in%` in `filter`?

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider

```
df = data.frame(col1 = 1:3, col2 = 2:4)
```

I want to do

```
df %>%
  filter(col1 %in% 2:3)
```

which should return the 2nd and 3rd row, but `col1` is passed in as a string as variable `str_1 = "col1"`

So I tried

```
  str_1 = "col1"
  df %>% 
    filter(!!!str_1 %in% 2:3)

  df %>% 
    filter(!!str_1 %in% 2:3)
```

and niether worked. What's the right syntax for this? And what's an easier way to remember these dplyr tricks?

Comment: `df %>% filter(!!sym(str_1) %in% 2:3)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter_at` when the you have column names as strings.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter_at(str_1, any_vars(. %in% 2:3))
#This seems to work as well
#df %>% filter_at(str_1, ~. %in% 2:3)

#  col1 col2
#1    2    3
#2    3    4
```

`filter_at` like all other `_at` variants in `dplyr` has a `.vars` arguments which accepts a character vector of column names or positions to apply a function.

Comment: explain what filter_at means?

Comment: @xiaodai Added some explanation.